# No option for "External Tools" in Kate plugins

Tags: linux-mint, kate

I was reading *Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux* by Jeff Duntemann, and in a chapter he told to configure Kate and enable *External Tools*.

Then I faced the problem. I am using Linux Mint 18.1 and using Kate version 15.12.3, I could not find *External Tools* in plugins. There is no option for it. I have also installed Kwrite and as said in the book that should have installed the necessary plugins for Kate. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *External Tools* plugin was disabled around 2011/2012, due to lack of [maintainer](https://kate-editor.org/2011/08/09/maintainer-needed-kate-external-tools-plugin/) support.

Information about currently supported plugins can be found [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/kate/plugins.html).

Answer (score 2):

A Kate developer here: The External Tools plugin is back with the KDE Applications 19.12 release, see:
https://kate-editor.org/post/2019/2019-09-21-external-tools-plugin/